# IntelliJ: How do I disable "Include non-project files" in the Navigate File control by default?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the `Navigate > File` option in IntelliJ IDEA (12.1.6) all the time (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) to navigate around my project, but I was wondering if there was a way to have the "Include non-project files" option disabled by default?

I know I can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> again, but I'm a lazy developer and wonder if there's a way to do it without the extra keystrokes. :)

Comment: Mine is disabled by default(2020.2.3)... Anyway, actually I arrived at this question in finding a way to enable this option. And your "hit it again" method saved me from using mouse to click the checkbox thus solved my problem(to some extent)! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such option. Please see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75550 for somewhat related problem.

Comment: Too bad. :/ Thanks anyway!